# How to Disable hardware acceleration in firefox using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I want to disable the hardware acceleration in firefox by using jquery or javascript.

Comment: could you explain a little more about what do you want to achieve?

Comment: To avoid the flickering of images in firefox its needed to disable the hardware acceleration. options >> Advanced and uncheck disable hardware acceleartion. But i want to do it via code. since i can't ask all the user to do it manually.

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but have a quick read of this https://davidwalsh.name/translate3d

Answer (score 4):

You can disable hardware acceleration for yourself by adding `user_pref("layers.acceleration.disabled", true);` to you profile's `prefs.js` file. You cannot change someone else's browser settings.

Comment: `%ppdata%/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/<profile>/prefs.js` or `~/.mozilla/firefox/<profile>/prefs.js`